# Sequentially ngresource calls

Tags: angularjs, rest, ngresource, angularjs-ng-resource

I have a controller making two $resource calls against two REST services where the result of the first one is used as input by the second one.

Here the code:

```js
if (requestLock == false) {
    $scope.T_01_04_sharedData.tempRequestForT_01_04 = insertNewRequest("aggr_1", $rootScope.globals.currentUser.username, "", "temp", "2016-07-30 00:00:00");
    requestLock = true;
}

if (action == 'add') {
    updateSelectedForRequest(prosumer, 'selected', $rootScope.globals.currentUser.username, $scope.T_01_04_sharedData.tempRequestForT_01_04);
} else {
    updateSelectedForRequest(prosumer, 'non-selected', $rootScope.globals.currentUser.username, $scope.T_01_04_sharedData.tempRequestForT_01_04);
}
```

**Function updateSelectedForRequest**

```js
function updateSelectedForRequest(username, status, businessUser, request) {
            WidgetService.T_01_04_updateSelectedForRequest.query({
                businessUser_id: businessUser,
                request_id: request,
                username: username,
                status: status
            }, function (result) {
                // response handler

            });
        }
```

**Function insertNewRequest**

```js
function insertNewRequest(bu_id_target, requester, description, status, validUntil) {
            return WidgetService.T_01_04_insertNewRequest.query({
                bu_id_target: bu_id_target, 
                requester: requester,
                description: description,
                status: status,
                validUntil: validUntil

            }, function (result) {

                $scope.T_01_04_sharedData.tempRequestForT_01_04 = result.request_id;
                return result;
            });
        }
```

The error is that the first call is not resolved sequentially so the second one has no input.

Is there the possibility to run these two calls sequentially in order to wait for the second call the input from the first one?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you want to wait the end of an action to execute a second one, then you should use Promises.

Comment: @Yoann can you make an example please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with ngresource, but you can try something like this.

```js
if (requestLock == false) {
    insertNewRequest("aggr_1", $rootScope.globals.currentUser.username, "", "temp", "2016-07-30 00:00:00")
    .then(function(result){
         $scope.T_01_04_sharedData.tempRequestForT_01_04 = result;

         if (action == 'add') {
              updateSelectedForRequest(prosumer, 'selected', $rootScope.globals.currentUser.username, $scope.T_01_04_sharedData.tempRequestForT_01_04);
         } else {
              updateSelectedForRequest(prosumer, 'non-selected', $rootScope.globals.currentUser.username, $scope.T_01_04_sharedData.tempRequestForT_01_04);
         }
    }, function(error){/* manage error here */});

    requestLock = true;
}
```

```js
function insertNewRequest(bu_id_target, requester, description, status, validUntil) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                PromiseWidgetService.T_01_04_insertNewRequest.query({
                    bu_id_target: bu_id_target, 
                    requester: requester,
                    description: description,
                    status: status,
                    validUntil: validUntil

                }, function (result) {

                    $scope.T_01_04_sharedData.tempRequestForT_01_04 = result.request_id;
                    resolve(result);
                });
            })
        }
```

more information on promise here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise